# CodeIgniter: delete file after completing download

Tags: codeigniter

I searched for a few hours but I didn't get exactly what I wanted. I am developing a website using CodeIgniter. I can zip the files using the CodeIgniter default [ZIP lib](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/zip.html) but I don't know how to delete after download.

I searched in the internet, most of the results I am getting are related to the normal delete function like unlink. But I want to do that after the download, and it has to integrate in CodeIgniter.

Please guide me to solve this issue.

Thanks to all.

Comment: sorry, can you explain in detail please

Comment: hey i accepted the previous question answers

Comment: which file you want to delete. a zip file or other files which you created zip from

Comment: i want to delete the zip file after downloads like download.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following code to offer a download:

```
header("Content-Type:$mimetype");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
header("Cache-Control:must-revalidate,post-check=0,pre-check=0");
header("Content-Length:".filesize($temp_filename));
readfile_chunked($temp_filename);
```

(readfile_chunked comes from
http://nl2.php.net/manual/nl/function.readfile.php)

My question: how can I check if the file was downloaded and saved? I want to
make an automatic removal possible after download.

The function seems to exit when the user clicks cancel and doesn't download
the file, so all following commands will not get executed. That's perfect.

However, it doesn't when the file is small enough to fit in a chunk. php's
readfile seems to have the same behaviour. So, in that case, all following
commands do get executed, even if cancel was clicked (and in my application,
the file then gets removed, which shouldn't happen of course).

Also checking the bytes sent doesn't help. If the function exists, it always
returns the complete filesize for the small files that fit in a single
chunk, even if cancel was clicked.

So, is there any working way to determine if a file was downloaded and
opened/saved instead of cancel being clicked in the download dialog